# StartCopyFromBlob not working with Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I have Azure Storage SDK 2.0 (which internally includes storage client library 1.7.0). I am using following method to copy blob from S to T.

```
var blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(azureBlobName);

blockBlob.StartCopyFromBlob(new Uri(amazonObjectUrl), null, null, null);
```

But am getting following error:

```
Error   2   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlob' does not contain 
a definition for 'CopyState' and no extension method 'CopyState' accepting a first argument
of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlob' could be found (are you missing a 
using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Can you please help me out?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using version 1.7 of the storage client library?

Comment: No there is no reason why i would want to use **1.7.0** but while i download the azure storage package from NuGet, it automatically adds SCL 1.7.0. I would want to use 2.0 or 1.7.1 but am not able to.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is get rid of all references of the old library. So your code should not be having any references to `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient` namespace. Instead your code should be using `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage`, `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth` and `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob` namespaces which are part of 2.0 version of the library.

If it's a brand new project, then you should be OK. However if it's an old project which you're trying to upgrade, there're some changes in 2.0 version of the library which will break the code making use of 1.7 version. You may find this blog post useful if you're migrating from 1.7 to 2.0: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/11/28/storage-client-library-2-0-migrating-blob-storage-code/

Comment: But if i remove Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient then how can i continue using StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey method? I am using your code piece found at [link](http://gauravmantri.com/2012/06/14/how-to-copy-an-object-from-amazon-s3-to-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-copy-blob/)

Comment: You would need to make use of `StorageCredentials` class in `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth` namespace. The blog post was written with 1.7.1 library. 2.0 version came quite some time after that.